# Asp.net culture how to set it properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, cultureinfo, culture

I am trying to set the culture in my application. Here is my code :

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-CA");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr");
```

I am trying to set it to the MasterPage.master first. I have the **MasterPage.master.resx** and the **MasterPage.master.fr.resx**. The two file are set as Embedded Ressouce in the properties.

Here's my aspx element :

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="" ID="lnkLangue" OnClick ="lnkLangue_Click" meta:resourcekey="lnklangue" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

I have set the lnkLangue.Text in the both resx file (en and fr).

My problem is the culture is always in english and never in french. I can set the culture to     "fr-CA", nothing work (no french, only english). **I tried to set the culture in the PageLoad event, Preinit, on a button click, etc**, Nothing work.

I am using the framework 4.0

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Where, exactly, do you set the culture? Which event?

Comment: This is what I dont know, where to set it ? I tried everywhere

Comment: Define "everywhere" by showing us some code.

Comment: In the pageload event, preinit, on a button click, I said it in the question

Comment: Try the PreInit event on a page, not the master page and see if that works. Also, please confirm that the resources work at all, by changing the English version of the resource and seeing if that displays on the page.

Comment: Also, try using `<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto">` in web.config. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.

Comment: ty John for your help, but the problem is I wasn't setting the culture in the right event... The right one is InitializeCulture. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to override the following method on each page that needs to be localized, or inherit from a base page that overrides the InitializeCulture method.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-CA");
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr");
   base.InitializeCulture();
}
```